# Kotlin enum Class with companion object integrate with field of the Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, android-things

[Nilhcem/i2cfun-androidthings](https://github.com/Nilhcem/i2cfun-androidthings/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nilhcem/androidthings/i2cfun/device/components/ArduinoFanI2C.kt)

What modifications would I have to make in the code above, to make the result of this line:

```
companion object {
    fun fromValue (i2cValue: Int) = Speed.values (). firstOrNull {it.i2cValue == i2cValue}?: MEDIUM
```

which in the case is static (MEDIUM) in dynamic, ie, I  want to get this value from a `firebase` field

I have this project below that was forkado of said Project:[link](https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive5/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/neube/smartdrive/device/components/SmartDriveDriver.kt)

in this line:

```
companion object {
    fun fromValue(motorneuber: Byte) = MotorNumber.values().firstOrNull { it.motorneuber == motorneuber } ?: Two
```

the Two OR One, depending on the case,  will come from a firebase field.

The field will be of type string and if in such field is the word One turns One if it has Two turns Two.

Comment: I've been researching a lot and I think the answer has to do with this project, and some more adaptations: https://github.com/FrangSierra/KotlinFirechat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/frangsierra/kotlinfirechat/session/model/LoginProvider.kt

Comment: So you want to turn a string into an enum?

Comment: May I ask what you've tried? You mention that you researched a lot, have any of the solutions you've found worked? If not - why? Please narrow down your question, right now it sounds pretty much like "how do I solve my problem using Firebase?".

Comment: @NickFelker I want to turn a bytes from firebase field an enum.

Comment: @Egor How do I solve my problem using Firebase and enum?, that is correct. What do you think I should do?  step by step, pls. Today, I staying thinking in use rxjava2/enum/firebase: https://josiassena.com/eventbus-with-rxjava2-using-kotlin/  (to solve my issue)

Comment: Can you just do a switch statement that takes in the byte?

Comment: @NickFelker with switch code is more complicated/verbose, I prefer enum (look before and after): https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-YeKQ8-ps8NMZRTum1Q9czAWX-FOoyT/view?usp=sharing   
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SOkH8nG93hqQwrJ9L3OiA7otEN-yaWXo/view?usp=sharing    
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkSfVit7wSal3CKNUAapuCtrQ3Xlki3c/view?usp=sharing